# According to this tutorial where have I to create this class in my Laravel project (a class implementing the UserProviderInterface interface)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am abslolutly new in **PHP** and moreover in **Laravel** framework (I came from Java).

I am following this tutorial to create a custom authentication driver:

http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/115/using-your-own-authentication-driver

I have a very newbye doubt: at the beginning of this tutorial it show that I have to create a class that implements **UserProviderInterface**.

It only show the code but not where this class have to be put into my Laravel project. The only clue about its positioning is the **namespace**:

```
namespace MyApp\Extensions;
```

But exactly where have I to put it?

**I have the following structure:**

[image]

It say to put it into **MyApp\Extensions** but I have not **MyApp** and **Extension** folder in my project? (or maybe the nampespaces name doesn't reflect a directory structure into the project tree?)

So where have I to create this class?

Comment: Found this : `Create an Auth directory inside the app root (or in a place of your preference) and create the User Provider Interface implementation. I will name the file as CustomUserProvider.php` here https://laravel.io/forum/11-04-2014-laravel-5-how-do-i-create-a-custom-auth-in-laravel-5?page=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want it to go inside `MyApp\Extensions`, consider `MyApp` as the `app` folder.

Then only thing to do is create a folder named `Extensions` inside `app` folder and create your `UserProviderInterface.php` there.

But If I were you, I'd create it under `app\Auth\Providers\UserProviderInterface.php`

Answer (score 1):

I believe what the page author meant was to create a folder named `Extensions` and create the provider file under `app/Extensions` folder. `MyApp` is just a custom namespace that the author chose, that in default laravel app, it should be `App`.

Which means, if you create a folder `Extensions` under `app` folder, the `DummyAuthProvider` should then be in the namespace of `namespace App\Extensions;`